# How to add firebase google login method to a django app

Tags: python, django, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am developing a Django web application and I would like to integrate Firebase Google Login for user authentication. I have gone through the Firebase documentation, but I couldn't find a direct approach for implementing Google Login in Django.

I would like to know how I can add Firebase Google Login to my Django app. Specifically, I would like to achieve the following:

Allow users to sign in to my Django app using their Google accounts.
Retrieve user information such as email, name, and profile picture from Google after successful authentication.
Save the authenticated user to Firebase Authentication for further authentication and authorization.
I have already set up Firebase for my project and obtained the necessary service account JSON file. I have also installed the required packages like firebase-admin,

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.